# iPhone Game Center iOS4 support my game? How?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ios4, iphone-4

I'm currently building a multiplayer game for the iOS4 and I am trying to understand how I can make it support Game Center when it is released?

Is there ANY documentation on it? I can't find it anywhere

I'm using cocos2d to build my game and am currently not finished, but would like to be able to code directly in hopes of the game being used on the Game Center so I dont have to back track

thanks for the help!

Comment: Game Center is still in beta which means its under NDA and can only be discussed in the Apple developer forums.

Answer (score 1):

You must enable Game Center for your game and create at least one scoreboard in iTunesConnect to test Game Center.